# How to read a data point from a text file in C

Tags: c, parsing, input

I have a text file full of points of the following format on different lines

LONG,LONG

i can successfully read each line and print it out, but I how can I parse the string in C such that I get each long of each point on its own?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to show your program that reads and prints the lines, to provide a better starting point for the discussion.

Comment: You say below that you're really after floats, which makes this very confusing. Please consider including some of the contents of the data file in the question, to help clarify the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have the line already, it's easiest to use [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) to do this:

```
long a, b;

if(sscanf(line, "%ld,%ld", &a, &b) == 2)
{
  /* Successfully parsed two long integers, now store them somewhere I guess. */
}
```

Note that it's a good idea to check the return value of `sscanf()`, this protects you from wrongly accepting illegal data and getting undefined results.

You can do it in multiple steps too if you need more control, as @dasblinkenlights suggested. You can use `strtol()` to parse the first number from the start of the line, then if that succeeds look for the comma, and then parse the second number. It *can* be faster than `sscanf()`, but I wouldn't expect too much for something this simple.

Comment: hmm it works, but it reads the first number as an integer....
here is what i'm doing
     
long x;
  long y;
  sscanf(line,"%ld,%ld",&x,&y);
  printf("x:%ld\n",x);

Comment: @user2347153 What? A `long` is an integer ... not sure what you mean.

Comment: never mind.... my brain just derped heavily.... I had meant to say floats >.<"... I need the format to be for floats

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions to this.

One is to read the line, read the first `long` with [`strtol`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strtol.html) find the position of the comma that follows with [`strchr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html), and read the second number from there.

Another solution would be to read the line, and pass it to [`sscanf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sscanf.html) function with the format that accepts two comma-separated `LONG`s.

Comment: can you tell me what the format is please? I'm sort of a beginner

Comment: see meaning-matters answer. he posted the complete function call, including the format string.

Comment: @user2347153 format is the first parameter of `scanf` (or the second parameter of `sscanf`, because the first parameter is the data buffer). In your case the format string would look like `"%ld,%ld"`, or `"%lld,%lld"` if you use the `long long` data type.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string variant of `scanf()` if you say you've already got the line:

```
char* line;
long long1;
long long2;

sscanf(line, "%ld,%ld", &long1, &long2);
```

Indeed as @unwind suggests in his +1 answer, it's a very good idea to check the return value of `scant()`, which is the number of successfully read values.